# Items not centering inside of grid container

Tags: css, css-grid

I am having trouble centering a heading and text element in a 2x2 grid. I have already tried using justify-content/items/self on the parent container ".skills", and the child-elements ".skills-item". Also, note that the grid is inside a flex container, I do not know if that has anything to do with it but I am clueless.

```css
.about {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12.8rem 8rem 6.4rem 8rem;
  background-color: #ebebff;
}

.backstory {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 60rem;
  margin-bottom: 4.8rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.skills {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  row-gap: 4.8rem;
  column-gap: 6.4rem;
  justify-items: center;
}

.skills-item {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
  <div class="backstory">
    <h2>Hi, I'm Mayitu Wangala</h2>
    <p>
      I'm a software developer. I became interested in computer science in college and became immersed in the world of IT. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos cum magni similique adipisci.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="skills">
    <!--Rename/regroup skills later-->
    <div class="skills-item 3-lang">
      <h3 class="skills-heading">HTML, CSS, Javascript</h3>
      <p>
        My knowledge of HTML, CSS, and javascript allows me to create beautiful, responsive projects and websites.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="skills-item python">
      <h3 class="skills-heading">Python</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos cum magni similique adipisci
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="skills-item data-structures">
      <h3 class="skills-heading">Data Structures</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos cum magni similique adipisci
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="skills-item design">
      <h3>Design</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos cum magni similique adipisci
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the parent class as flexbox in order to align the child elements as you wish.

```
 .skills-item{
    display:flex;
    }
```

Since the text inside **p** tags won't seem like centered, even if it is, you can try to use `text-align:center;`.